turtoise: setting windows credentials only lasts one time
I changed my password of gitlab.
Now, I want to use turtoise again like I did it before. I found out that I have to change the password in turtoise/settings/Git/Credential. There, I can access the Windows Credential Manager. I open it and change the password. However, that change only works for exactly one time: (one push or one pull). After that one push or pull, the old password is again there.
How can I change the password permanently in turtoise?
(I tried pressing the "Open settings" button before and thought that this leads to opening the Windows Credential Manager in Admin mode - but that didn't work either. (same result: password change lasts only one single time))

Are you talking about TortoiseGit? If so, it would help if you added the respective tag.

What exactly is "turtoise"?
